# Timing: how make a program to work faster using built in functions and tables

Tags: plotting, functions, performance-tuning

I want to improve my code to make it working faster even for very large numbers.

```
fun[n_, a_, b_] := (
  low = n^a;
  low2 = n^b;
  p = Table[Binomial[n, x]*StirlingS2[a, x]*x!/low, {x, 1, a}];
  pp = Table[Binomial[n, x]*StirlingS2[b, x]*x!/low2, {x, 1, b}];
  ListPlot[{p // N, pp // N}, some options]
)
```

I know that I should use as many built-in functions as I can, so I made it. And also I should not repeat the same thing many times. 
I want to run this function for values like for example $n = 1000000, a = 800000, b = 800000$. Is it possible to improve the speed of the program? And is it possible to evaluate the function for such huge numbers in a reasonable time (for example less than 2 hours)? Maybe is any way to make working on tables faster?

Comment: Try `p=Binomial[n,#] StirlingS2[a,#] #!/low/@Range[a]`, functional programming is often faster than procedural programming in *Mathematica*. (`Map`, that is `/@`, is functional and `Table` is procedural.)

Comment: @Pickett Are you sure it works good, because when I used that it has problem to understand the sign `#` and no plot is generated, because the values are not evaluated correctly

Comment: Sorry, there is a typo. It should be `&/@Range[a]`. Look up "pure functions" in the documentation.

Comment: @Pickett Yes, I found this typo. Thanks, this modification really increased a little bit the speed, but still not enough for huge numbers.

Comment: Do you have some small n,a,b and the picture,so that I can test my code?